# Can't pull image after successful login in ECR

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr, podman

I have already made many sucessfull push/pull to ECRs in different accounts using the ECR policy with no problems.

Now I'm using Podman/WSL in Windows and faced with an unusual situation. Docker/ECR Login works, the Resource policy is OK, pull doesn't work.

```
[root@GFT-79QHVP3-NB .aws]# aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | podman login --username AWS --password-stdin
 123456.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Login Succeeded!
[root@GFT-79QHVP3-NB .aws]# podman pull 123456.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/amundsen:pantalla
Trying to pull 123456.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/amundsen:pantalla...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob 326f452ade5c [--------------------------------------] 0.0b / 4.9MiB
Copying blob 15132af73342 [--------------------------------------] 0.0b / 6.0MiB
Copying blob 8ffa7aaef404 [--------------------------------------] 0.0b / 187.7MiB
Copying blob a42821cd14fb [--------------------------------------] 0.0b / 10.4MiB
Copying blob 8471b75885ef [--------------------------------------] 0.0b / 52.1MiB
Copying blob 23858da423a6 [--------------------------------------] 0.0b / 52.5MiB
Copying blob a81a13cb42bc [--------------------------------------] 0.0b / 14.8MiB
Copying blob 39baa166dda6 [--------------------------------------] 0.0b / 233.0b
Copying blob 28d172f530ba [--------------------------------------] 0.0b / 2.8MiB
Copying blob 675c578c2119 [--------------------------------------] 0.0b / 166.0b
Copying blob b1d5411ecaa3 [--------------------------------------] 0.0b / 583.0b
Copying blob c295868a77a0 [--------------------------------------] 0.0b / 6.5MiB
Copying blob 520ddae1a49a [--------------------------------------] 0.0b / 99.4MiB
Copying blob 1c076a62ab4f [--------------------------------------] 0.0b / 208.9MiB
Error: reading blob sha256:23858da423a6737f0467fab0014e5b53009ea7405d575636af0c3f100bbb2f10: unable to retrieve auth token: invalid username/password: unauthorized: authentication required
```

The resource policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowPushPull",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::78910:root"
      },
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
        "ecr:PutImage",
        "ecr:UploadLayerPart"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I wasn't able to find the Docker credentials anywhere. And from this podman env I was able to connect to other ECRs and do push/pulls. I'm lost here.

I have tried a little more verbosity and forcing the pull command to use the authfile. Still no game.

```
[root@GFT-79QHVP3-NB containers]# aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | podman login --username AWS --password-stdin xxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com --verbose
Used:  /run/user/0/containers/auth.json
Login Succeeded!

[root@GFT-79QHVP3-NB containers]# podman pull xxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/amundsen:pantalla --authfile=/run/user/0/containers/auth.json
<same error as above>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the right IAM permissions? I am assuming you're attempting this as `arn:aws:iam::78910:root` right?

Comment: Yes, I got the login working. I'm running it logged as an AdminRole in "78910".

Comment: Could you try running podman with higher verbosity to see if we can maybe get more info of what's going on?

Comment: Added more details and steps.

Comment: Great, could you also try running the pull command with `--verbose`?

Comment: No such param in the "pull" command. =(

Comment: Can you check the contents of the `auth.json` file? Also you can try this for more info: `podman login --get-login xxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Contents of json file looks ok, a giant token. get-login returned "AWS", which is what it should have.